# Positive synonym for sacrifice

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a positive synonym for the word sacrifice. Something that highlights the positive qualities needed to sacrifice the old and go with the new.

Comment: The word *sacrifice* has four or five meanings as a noun, and a similar number as a verb. Which meaning do you want?

Comment: I'd say sacrifice is always seen as promising a profitable outcome (a 'meaningless sacrifice' is when one calculates wrongly). 'Self-sacrificial' means one is putting the good of others before one's own (usually temporary) state.

Comment: Could you not just call it *Acceptance*? It's not really a sacrifice if you'd be better of migrating.

Answer (score 3):

***"Trade up"*** and ***"modernize"***, within certain contexts address the concept of replacing old with new but they do not express any pain associated with that exchange.  The best word I can think of is your subject word, ***"sacrifice"***, used *in conjunction* with another word or two to make a very clear expression such as:

> "***Sacrificing*** familiarity for speed and added functionality"
>
> or
>
> "***Giving up*** his *_*_ for a newer model was a small price to pay"

Answer (score 1):

"Creative destruction" is the term in an economical context.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation, which is subtly different than the title, such a change might be described as

> Renewal

or

> Fresh start

for that sense of "out with the old, in with the new".

Answer (score 0):

What about "*giving one's life*"?